# Normalizing data collected over varying time slots

Tags: algorithms

First, it's been a while since I have done any 'maths'. I have data collected from sensors over possibly varying timeslots (Only one sensor can collect at a time). I am attempting an algorithm that would adjust the length of time for each sensor based on the proportion of data it collects compared to the other sensors. In short if a sensor collects an amount of data under a certain threshold, the length of time it is granted will be decreased and if it collects data over a certain threashold it will be increased (only upto a max) otherwise it will maintain it's current alloted time. The problem is that sensors that have decreased timeslots and then begin to collect data will not have enough time to collect enough data to pass the high threshold. I want to base the amount of data on the proportion of time the sensor has. I think normalization is what I am looking for.

So, in short this is what I have come up with:

If each $t_i$ is the length of time that sensor $s_i$ can collect on and $d_i$ is the 'amount' of data collected by $s_i$ during that time then:

Let $T = \sum_{i=0}^n t_i$ i.e. the total length of time

Let $D = \sum_{i=0}^n d_i$ i.e. the total data collected

Then I have $Pt_i = t_i/T$ is the proportion of time sensor $s_i$ has and $Pd_i = d_i/D$ is the proportion of data collected by sensor $s_i$.

So, my question is, would taking the result of $Pd_i * Pt_i$ and using that to determine whether or not the time slot should be increased, decreased or remain as is valid?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Proportional Share Scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_share_scheduling) that is used for CPU time resource allocation.

Start by granting all your sensors the same share, then adjust their share periodically based on the proportion of data that actually collect. You'll have to determine a reasonable time interval to do the re-evaluation.

If the amount of data the sensors collect is constant (although different for each sensor) the time allocation should settle over time.